# Find & Replace digit by digit and space in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, replace, find, sublimetext3, digit

I have lot of digits and I want to add spaces in between them, like so:

`0123456789` --> `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

I'm trying to do this using the search and replace function in Sublime Text. What I've tried so far is using `\S` to find all characters (there are only digits so it doesn't matter) and `\1\s` to replace them. However, this deletes the digits and replaces them with `s`. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a combination of [Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions to do this. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*, input the following and click **Replace All**

```
Find What: (?<=\d)(?=\d)
Replace With: empty space
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vM8iM5)

---

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=        # look behind to see if there is:
  \d        #   digits (0-9)
)           # end of look-behind
(?=         # look ahead to see if there is:
  \d        #   digits (0-9)
)           # end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Search and Replace dialog (make sure you click the `.*` at the left to enable regular expression mode):

- Search for: `(\d)(?!$)`
- Replace with: `$1[space]`

The regular expression `(\d)(?!$)` matches all the digits except the one at the end of the line.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern `(\d)(?=\d)` and replace with `$1` <- $1{space}
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zD1kB1)